# Every neighbourhood of $1$ is of form $U\setminus \mathbb{N} \cup \{1\}$?

Tags: general-topology

From Topology without tears:

Let $X$ be a set $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N})\cup {1}$.

Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to X$:
\begin{equation}
f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      x & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$}\\
      1 & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{N}$}
     \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Further define topology $\tau $ on $X$ by

$$\tau=\{U:U\subseteq X \text { and } f^{-1}(U) \text{ is open  in the euclidean topology on } \mathbb{R} \}$$

Then prove:
1)$f$ is continuous.

2)Every open neighbourhood of $1$ in (X,\tau) is of form $(U\setminus \mathbb{N}) \cup \{1\}$,where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

I am not getting how every open neighbourhood of $1$ in $(X,\tau)$ of form $U\setminus \mathbb{N} \cup \{1\}$

Because this open neighbourhood will also be a open set in $(X,\tau)$.And According to me, if a $S\subseteq X$ contains $1$,then $f^{-1}(S)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)\in S\}$ will also contain $\mathbb{N}$(since for $\forall x \in \mathbb{N},f(x)=1\in S)$.Then in that case how $f^{-1}(S)$ will be open in eucliedean topology??As $\mathbb{N}$ is itself not open in Euclidean topology in \mathbb{R}??

And hence according to me,none of the open set in $(X,\tau)$ must contain $1$

Any hint  where I am wrong is appreciable.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is $\mathbb N$. To give an example of $S\subset X$ open, pick a neighborhood $U_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $S_0=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}U_n$, and $S=(S_0\setminus\mathbb N)\cup\{1\}$. Then we have $f^{-1}(S)=S_0$, which is open in $\mathbb R$.

Now, can you prove that every open sets in $X$ containing $1$ looks like that?

Comment: @nachosemu Sorry, I mistyped `cup` to `cap`. Does it look nicer now?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! ^^

Comment: Now got your point, amazing hint! Bests

Comment: @nachosemu And thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: Next step probably: $X$ is not first countable at $1$. $X=\Bbb R{/}\Bbb N$, quotient of identifying the naturals to a point.